# Automount USB exFAT drives with Synology NAS

Tags: linux, nas, synology, automount, exfat-fuse

I installed a library for exFAT support and I have to manually mount it via SSH. I would like to get it to operate as it does out of the box with drives that are FAT formatted, where  appears as one of its shared folders.

The command I am using is something like this:

```
/mount.exfat-fuse /dev/sds1 /volume1/homes/admin/exFAT
```

I am not sure of the mechanics of how the NAS does it automatically with its OS. I figure it might be similar to how other Linux OS's do it.

Background instructions for adding exFAT support are here: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=62473&start=90#p390456

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites http://serverfault.com OR http://SuperUser.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.